# AWS S3 is there a notification on GetObject?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a usecase where I want to put data into an S3 bucket, for it to read later, by another account. I only want the other account to be able to read the file in S3, and once they have read it, I will then delete the file myself.

I have been reading the S3 documentation, and cannot see they cover this usecase: of sending a notification when a file in an S3 bucket is read ?

Can anyone help, or suggest an alternative workflow ? I have been looking at AWS SNS and was wondering if that would be a better solution ?

Comment: I think you're right that S3 doesn't have such an event. And if it doesn't then I guess there is nothing for SNS to hang on to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use CloudTrail and CloudWatch Events to enable this workflow.

By default S3 API calls are not logged so you'd want to enable that following the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html).

Then enable a CloudWatch event rule for the Simple Storage Service where the "GetObject" operation occurs.

Have this event invoke a Lambda function that will remove the object.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/log-s3-data-events.html).